# What happens in "watch" when the called command has not yet finished?

Tags: rsync, watch

A server produces large amounts of data which I'd like to download as continuosly as possible. The simplest idea is to just use

```
watch rsync ...
```

As far as I understand, `watch` will call `rsync` every 2 seconds.

The key question is then: What happens when `rsync` does not quit within those 2 seconds? Will it start a new `rsync` every 2 seconds no matter what or will it wait until the previous `rsync` has terminated?

Answer (score 14):

You can check this by running something like

```
watch "date >> watch.log; echo Sleeping; sleep 10"
```

which will use the default two-second interval. If you leave this to run a little while, you’ll see that `watch.log` records the date and time every twelve seconds — so `watch` runs its command, *waits for it to finish*, then waits for the configured interval before running the command again.

Answer (score 3):

Accordint to test with

```
watch updatedb
```

It waits for the program finish, before starting another session.

I'm not sure if it makes sense to run rsync with watch. If you want to trigger regular run, use cron.

If you want to run your rsync more frequently, write script with forever cycle (while true do) and use pgrep for detection of running rsync. If detected, wait your defined time and test in another iteration of the cycle.